# If $T$ is self-adjoint then $||T^n|| = ||T||^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. If $T$ is self-adjoint then $||T^n|| = ||T||^n$.

It is easy to see that $||T||^n$ is an upper bound. Indeed, there exists a $C>0$ such that, $||T^nx|| \leq C||x||$. Then $||T^n|| \leq ||T||^n$.

To prove the other direction, \begin{align*}||T||^2  = \sup_{||x|| =1}\{||Tx||^2\} & = \sup_{||x|| =1}\{\langle Tx,Tx\rangle\}= \sup_{||x|| =1}\{\langle x,TTx\rangle\} \\ & \leq \sup_{||x|| =1}\{||x||^2||T^2||\} = ||T^2||.\end{align*}

But for the case $n = 3$ (the induction step), it seems that trick I've used doesn't work. Since
\begin{align*}
||T||^3 = \sup_{||x|| =1}\{||Tx||^3\} & = \sup_{||x|| =1}\{\sqrt{\langle Tx,Tx\rangle}^3\}= \sup_{||x|| =1}\{\sqrt{\langle x,TTx\rangle}^3\} \\ & \leq \sup_{||x|| =1}\{\sqrt{||x||^2||T^2||}^3\} = ||T^2||^{\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{align*}

How to show the induction step? I read some comments using the spectral theorem but I have not learnt it yet. Is there another proof using just properties of being self-adjoint?

Answer (score 9):

By induction you have $\vert \vert T^{2^k}\vert \vert = \vert\vert T\vert\vert ^{2^k}$

So let $ 2^{k-1} <n <2^{k}$. If $\vert \vert   T^{n}\vert \vert < \vert\vert T\vert\vert ^{n}$, then   $\vert \vert   T^{2^k}\vert \vert \leq \|T^n\|\cdot\|T^{2^k-n}\|<\|T\|^n\cdot\|T\|^{2^k-n}=\|T\|^{2^k}$, contradiction

Comment: I edited a minor mistake, very nice and very simple answer, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is self-adjoint, then $\|T\|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}|\lambda|$. Likewise,
$$
             \|T^n\|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(T^n)}|\lambda|.
$$
By the spectral mapping theorem, $\sigma(T^n)=\sigma(T)^n$. So
$$
                \|T^n\|=\sup_{\lambda\in \sigma(T)}|\lambda^n|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}|\lambda|^n=\|T\|^n.
$$

Comment: The OP asks to avoid the spectral mapping theorem, but basically $\sigma(T^n) = \sigma(T)^n$ is the fundamental theorem of algebra so I give this a pass. +1

Comment: @Quantum : The OP wanted to avoid the spectral theorem, but I did appeal to the spectral mapping theorem, which is not so difficult, as you noted.